# Modeler - Editing Widget

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-modeler

I've been looking into how to edit widgets via modeler and struggling to find any information on it on here or on the web.

I've added a new string field to a vector layer which is pre-populated with string data and looking to change this to a Value Map widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was never able to find out a way to do this within the modeler, so the next best solutions seemed to be to add it via python;

Here is the code snippet that I use to add ValueMaps to layers, you'll need to change;

Layer_name - layer name you want to add your widget to.
'Option': 'Option' - what ever options you want to display via value map.

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsEditorWidgetSetup, QgsProcessingAlgorithm, QgsProcessing
class SetEditorWidget(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    
    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        pass
    
    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Layer_name')[0]
        fieldIndex = layer.fields().indexFromName( 'Layer_name' )
        editor_widget_setup = QgsEditorWidgetSetup( 'ValueMap', {
        'map': {'Option1': 'Option1',
        'Option2': 'Option2',
        'Option3': 'Option3',
        'Option4': 'Option4',
        'Option5': 'Option5',
        'ELSE': 'ELSE'}
        })
        layer.setEditorWidgetSetup( fieldIndex, editor_widget_setup )
        return {}
    
    def name(self):
        return 'SetEditorWidget'

def displayName(self):
    return 'SetEditorWidget'

def group(self):
    return ''

def groupId(self):
    return ''

def createInstance(self):
    return SetEditorWidget()
```